# Merge CPT Taxonomy and Post Taxonomy in $query->set

Tags: query, pre-get-posts

I'm merging blog posts and a custom post type into a single query and displaying them on my feed as well, here's the code:

```
function add_query_news_projects( $query ) {
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() || is_feed() )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'portfolio' ) );
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_query_news_projects' );
```

The issue I'm having is that blog posts have a taxonomy of "category" and the CPT has a taxonomy of "portfolio_category". I'd like to display the CPT category AS a category in my template AND in my RSS feed. Is there are means to rewrite the results of the $query with "porfolio_category" being "category" for those posts?

Comment: If you're just trying to *display* the terms/categories in the custom `porfolio_category` taxonomy, then you could just use functions like [`the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_terms/).. in your templates, e.g. the `single-your_post_type.php` file.

Comment: Thanks Sally! Unfortunately, the output is being displayed with Elementor Pro which allows only one taxonomy to be chosen. I was hoping that I could basically say in the resulting query to set portfolio_category AS category for the result.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you can't do that - there's the [`tax_query` argument](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters), but that doesn't seem to be what you're looking for? Hence, you may get a better luck asking on the Elementor's website or support forums - perhaps someone there already done what you're really trying to do.